# Cassandra : Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I installed cassandra on ubuntu16.04 using following commands -

```
  echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key A278B781FE4B2BDA
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install cassandra
```

When try to connect to cqlsh , it gives me error -

```
  Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Tired installing cassandra-driver as suggested [here](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-cassandra-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-run-a-single-node-cassandra-cluster-on-ubuntu.html). Still getting same error.

Am I missing anything?

However , if I start cassandra as a foreground process , i.e **sudo cassandra -f** , it works.

Comment: I think you have changed your rpc_address, try running cqlsh with rpc_address and cqlport. E.g cqlsh <rpc_address> <cqlport>

Comment: Did you start Cassandra ?

Comment: @ShobanSundar I tried with it. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

After you install Cassandra, start it via `service cassandra start` and then wait a few seconds. Then you will be able to access it via the cqlsh client.

However, the configuration files should be visible under /etc/cassandra/. Did you receive any error messages during the installation?

Comment: No logs are getting generated. If I start it as foreground process (edited question) , it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Cassandra is not installed properly. Can you share your work log during Cassandra installation? Did you see any warnings/errors?

Comment: Next time please ask for additional information in question's comments. It's no good to post this as answer.

Comment: No logs are getting generated. If I start it as foreground process (edited question) , it works.

Answer (score 0):

Running `cassandra` command will help you find the problem, you can also see the log file in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you started cassandra please check system.log and debug.log for any error while starting. Make sure you can see cassandra started in the logs. Also you need to check your rpc_address and listen address and try connect using rpc address and correct port. in this way you may connect cqlsh.